# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI j_spring_security_check in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Here's my spring security Bean

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="username" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

here's my MVC-dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.apsas" />



    <!-- Required for body marshalling -->

    <mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="apsaspu" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">

        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and here's my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/c")
public class MainController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {

        String name = principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form example");
        return "hello";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {

        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {

        return "login";

    }
    }
```

My problem is when im accessing the localhost:8080/apsas/c/welcome Im getting

```
HTTP ERROR 500

 Server Error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apsas.controller.MainController.printWelcome(MainController.java:30)
```

i can successfully go to login page but after clicking the submit button im getting, im getting http error 404 Problem accessing /apsas/c/j_spring_security_check.

and here's the log
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/apsas/c/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

i can successfuly accessed some page defined in my tiles except the welcome which should direct me to log in. please help

Comment: anyway i am using apache tiles

Comment: Can you show your login page?

Comment: Actually, never mind, I see the problem.

Comment: may i know the solution. please help.

Comment: Ha, I guess that seemed like I was just taking off.  I put the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default spring security login page is `[application context]/j_spring_security_check`

Your login page is submitting to `/apsas/c/j_spring_security_check`.  Assuming your app context is `apsas`, your login form should be submitting to `/apsas/j_spring_security_check` or `../j_spring_security_check`.

To be clear, this is the value of the `action` attribute of the `form` element on your login page.  If you need help, post your login page into the question and I can be more specific.

Comment: my form value is "j_spring_security_check"

il try to change it to "../j_spring_security_check"

thanks, will response in a second

Comment: when im logged out may i know how to redirect some of the page to log in page...

Anyway it works

Comment: when logging out then trying to go at http://localhost:8080/apsas/c/addStudentPage

im redirecting to http://localhost:8080/apsas/login

may i know how to redirect it into http://localhost:8080/apsas/c/login

Comment: you can specify the logged out page via the `logout-success-url` of the `<logout>` element in your security config xml

Comment: solved it now. just changed  <form-login login-page="/c/login" default-target-url="/c/welcome"
   authentication-failure-url="/c/loginfailed" /> hehe thanks a lot Mr. Taylor. i very thankful :)